# How to copy data from csv file into table with name user in Postgres?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I am trying to copy user information from csv file into Postgres database and the table name is `user`.

I can import data from **pgAdmin** manually. However if I run the `COPY user(columns) FROM csvfile...` command, it is giving me Syntax error at `user`.

Is there any solution for this?

When I renamed the `user` table to `usert`, it worked and I was able to insert data.

Is the issue because of the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is a reserved key word. Thus, you'll have to specify the table identifier as a **quoted identifier** it in double quotes:

```sql
COPY "user" (columns) FROM csvfile...
```

For more, consult the doc on [Lexical Structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html), specifically the section [Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).